# How to make split grouped column bar chart in highcharts with percentage?

Tags: highcharts

I need a chart similar to this [chart with radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmhQP.png)

[image: chart provides percentage]

where in chart it is grouped with country like Green -IN, Yellow-US, Orange-UK

and my data structure looks like

```
 [
  {
  "names":["App Launch","Add to cart"]
  },
  {
  "IN":[3,3],
  "US":[1,1],
  "UK":[4,2]
  }
 ]
```

As i am beginner in highcharts i had gone through with many grouping charts but i could not find one which i needed, Please do help with yours answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the radio button to switch between a percentage and a count, I suggest you redraw the chart with different attributes, rather than using groups. There is an attribute called `stacking` that you can set to either `percent` or `normal`. The `normal` value is what gets you your "count," or total number (see the documentation at https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stacking).

I've created a version of your chart with the radio button: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/1f4k8gop/. You can also take a look at the code snippet below. I added comments so you can see what's happening ... I hope that's helpful for you as a Highcharts beginner.

I put the Highcharts chart options into a variable (`chartOptions`). This way, you can change the options later on and redraw the chart with the new options. I set up a simple function (see the end of the Javascript part) that changes the `stacking` attribute whenever the radio buttons are clicked. This will redraw the chart to show the values as a percentage of total users or a count of total users. I then set a trigger so that the "percentage" option is chosen when the page is first loaded.

If you have any questions about how any of this works, leave me a comment and I'll be glad to explain.

Also: to answer another point in your question, groups wouldn't work. A column chart can only be stacked one way: either all values as a percentage, or all values as a count. You couldn't have both in the same chart, as shown in your picture. Groups are for comparing sets of columns among one another, rather than having them all stacked together.

```js
// set the chart options to a variable so we can change them later
var chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column', renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Use of our apps'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['App 1', 'App 2', 'App 3']
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of users'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
     // for this formatter function, we want to change what
      // shows up in the box based on whether we're showing 
      // a count or a percentage of the values
      formatter: function () {
        var total = 0; // the total of the values we're showing
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>'; // tooltip header
        // go through each item in the column
        $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
          switch(this.series.options.stacking) {
            case 'percent':
              s += this.series.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,0) + '<br/>';
              total += this.percentage;
              break;
            case 'normal':
              s += this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>';
              total += this.y;
              break;
          } 
        });
        return s + 'Total: ' + total;
      }, shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal' // this will be our default
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'IN',
        data: [5, 3, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'US',
        data: [2, 5, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'UK',
        data: [3, 0, 4]
    }]
};

// whenever someone clicks on a radio button, draw the chart
$('.ToggleFormRadio').click(function() {
  switch($(this)[0].value) {
   case 'percentage':
     chartOptions.plotOptions.column.stacking = 'percent';
      chartOptions.yAxis.title.text = 'Number of users (%)';
      var chart = Highcharts.chart(chartOptions);
      break;
   case 'count':
     chartOptions.plotOptions.column.stacking = 'normal';
      chartOptions.yAxis.title.text = 'Number of users';
      var chart = Highcharts.chart(chartOptions);
      break;
  }
});

// when the page is first loaded, trigger a click for the default
$('#ToggleFormRadio1').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<form id="ToggleForm">
  <input type="radio" name="ToggleFormRadio" class="ToggleFormRadio" id="ToggleFormRadio1" value="percentage" checked="checked"><label for="ToggleFormRadio1" >Percentage</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ToggleFormRadio" class="ToggleFormRadio" id="ToggleFormRadio2" value="count"><label for="ToggleFormRadio2">Count</label>
</form>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Small addition to your answer: `stack` option (don't confuse it with `stacking`) may be helpful too: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stack It should solve the problem with groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,this might help me to solve other scenario, but for my current problem i need like funneling, to show users conversion from 1st step to 2nd step so stacking wont work for me, i need the same with grouping. Is there any other method to achieve this ??

Comment: @pinkygifty I'm not sure I quite understand what you're looking for. Do you have another example or image you can show?